# Page not load with Google App Engine and python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

First I would like to apologise because I don't know exactly how to explain it.

I am using jinja2 and the BaseHandler and render is the function to respone.write my html.

The following code work without a problem:

```
class CategoryHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, *a, **kw): 
        sURL = self.request.url.split("-")
        category = sURL[-1]
        question = Questions.gql("WHERE tags='%s'"%sURL[-1]).run()
        self.render("allquestions.html",questions=question)

PAGE_RE = r'((?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/?)*)?'

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPageHandler)
                            ,('/category-'+PAGE_RE, CategoryHandler)
                            ],debug=True)
```

And the link is in this form `/category-football`

If I change the above code and instead of "-", I put the "/", when I try to load the page my pc start to warm up, the fan goes crazy and the page keep loading. After few minutes of really crazy fan, my pc restart.

If I change the  code it looks like this

```
    class CategoryHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, *a, **kw): 
        sURL = self.request.url.split("/")
        category = sURL[-1]
        question = Questions.gql("WHERE tags='%s'"%sURL[-1]).run()
        self.render("allquestions.html",questions=question)

PAGE_RE = r'((?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/?)*)?'

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPageHandler)
                            ,('/category/'+PAGE_RE, CategoryHandler)
                            ],debug=True)
```

and the link like this And the link is in this form `/category/football`

I cannot understand why the link work with the first way and I have this weird bug with the second way.

**UPDATE 1:**

I find something on the log of GAE.

On app.yamal I have set my static like this

```
  handlers:
- url: /assets
  static_dir: templates/assets
```

and on html template I call them like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

On the log console I see the following when I load the page

```
INFO     2013-05-29 16:42:26,197 server.py:585] default: "GET /category/assets/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Any help now?

Comment: surely / is used as an escape character for regex?

Comment: Are you talking about the PAGE_RE? I don't know a lot about this part. I take it as it is from a tutorial and add it to my code. Can I remove it somehow?

Comment: maybe try a double ("//")

Comment: I don't thin split() takes a regex, but this shouldn't be too hard to figure out if you step through with a debugger and see where you get stuck on an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and now load without a problem. But still I don't know why it was doing the infinite loop. In other situations, I had an error 500.

The problem was on the app.yamal and when I was calling the css&js files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

I add one more dot on the beggining. Problem solved but still wondering why I had this weird loop.